# How to make a proper function wrapper

Tags: python

I used naive approach to write a wrapper. Get all `*args` and `**kwargs` and pass them to the enclosing function. But something went wrong. So I simplified example to the core to illustrate my troubles.

```
# simplies wrapper possible: just pass the args
def wraps(f):
    def call(*argv, **kw):
        # add some meaningful manipulations later
        return f(*argv, **kw)
    return call

# check the wrapper behaves identically
class M:
    def __init__(this, param):
        this.param = param
M.__new__ = M.__new__
m1 = M(1)
M.__new__ = wraps(M.__new__)
m2 = M(2)
```

`m1` was instantiated normally, but `m2` fails with the following error description

```
 TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

The question is how to define `wraps` and `call` function properly so they would behave identically to the function being wrapped regardless of the wrapped function.

It is not the end objective obviously, since primitive `lambda x: x` would suffice. It is a starting point from which I could introduce further complications.

Comment: `M.__new__` isn't initially defined, so you are wrapping the inherited `object.__new__` method. The wrapper tries to pass its arguments to `object.__new__`, which doesn't accept any arguments. Did you mean to wrap `M.__init__` instead?

Comment: Do `M.__init__ = wraps(M.__init__)`, and it'll work just fine. You're doing `wraps` correctly, but you're messing around with class-level magic that can bite you if you're not careful.

Comment: @chepner that is the point. `m1` calls `object.__new__` unwrapped and succeeds. `m2` calls wrapped `object.__new__` and fails. Ergo the wrapper is not a proper wrapper. It loses original `object.__new__` ability to adapt to any arguments passed. So the question is how to define a wrapper that would hold all of the abilities of the wrapped function.

Comment: You don't need to wrap anything. You need to *define* `M.__new__`. Right now, `M.__new__` isn't an existing function that simply calls `object.__new__` , it's an expression that *resolves* to `object.__new__`.

Comment: It is an artificial example. It's made up to show non-equivalence of the wrapped function and original one. Obviously there is no need to define identical wrappers. But you could add some payload. Verification that would fail in some cases for example. P.S. edited the question to make the difference between expected and 
rejected more apparent

Comment: There is no "general" wrapper you can write. There's no clean way to get the signature of `f` so that you know which received arguments to pass on and which  to use internally only.

Comment: In the first case and in the second case `f` and wrapped `f` receive the same arguments. Either they should both succeed or both fail. But I got unexpected behavior where one fails and one succeeds. That means that I have insufficient knowledge of python language. Difference in behavior implies difference in definitions but I see no difference since I do not know where to look

Comment: `M.__call__` is receiving the same arguments in both cases. I'm trying to find a definitive reference to cite, but I don't believe that means that the call to `M.__new__` that it makes necessarily receives the same arguments in both cases.

Comment: I could suggest a hypothesis: `object.__new__` is a special function that is treated by the python interpreter differently from all other functions and that is why it could not be replicated with a wrapper?

Comment: You'll get the same error with any function that you try to pass unexpected arguments to. If you were defining `M.__new__` directly, you would take care to remove any arguments you receive that `M` itself adds to the signature before passing the rest on to `super().__new__`. Your wrapper doesn't, and can't, make the same determination, because it doesn't know anything about what `f` should and should not receive.

Comment: How could any wrapper exist in that case? I got all arguments and passed them all as is. But in case of directly calling inside a wrapper I got an error and in case of indirect call through class creation all things work ok. But the arguments were the same

Comment: @ivangolotin because you are assuming the problem is how the function is wrapped. It isn't. `M.__call__` decides, based on whether or not you overwrote `__new__` on how exactly to call it. If it sees that `__new__` is `object.__new__`, then you haven't defined it, and it calls it with no arguments. If you overwrote it, it calls it with all the arguments passed to `__call__`. When you do `M.__new__ = wraps(M.__new__)` it is considered to be overwritten, so it calls it with all arguments, hence the error

Comment: Alternately, you could argument you aren't calling the wrapped function correctly, *because* you are wrapping a function that can't take additional arguments. (This leads again to the difference between `M.__call__` and `M.__new__`.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I never know where to find this behavior in the docs, but you can look at the source code for a pretty decend (somewhat confusing) description of the behavior: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8a310dd5f4242b5d28013c1905c6573477e3b957/Objects/typeobject.c#L4412

Comment: @ivangolotin sorry, not `M.__call__`, but `type.__call__`, i.e. the *metaclass* `__call__`

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer**: *It's impossible*. You could not define a perfect wrapper in python (and in many other languages too).

**Slightly longer version**. Python function is a first-class object and all manipulations acceptable for objects could be performed with a function too. So you could not presume that some complex procedure would limit itself with only calling the function passed as argument and would not use the function object in other unobvious ways

**Much more verbose speculation with examples**

Functions defined only at part of the domain are pretty common

```
def half(i):
    if i < 0:
        raise ValueError
    if i & 1:
        raise ValueError
    return i / 2
```

Pretty straight. No we could get a little more confusing:

```
class Veggy:
    def __init__(this, kind):
        this.kind = kind
    def pr(this):
        print(this.kind)

def assess(v):
    if v.kind in ['tomato', 'carrot']:
        raise ValueError
    v.pr()
```

Here `Veggy` used as a function proxy but also have public property `kind` which the assess function check before executing.

The same thing could be done with a function object since it also have additional properties besides calling.

```
def test(x):
    return x + x

def assess4(f, *argv, **kw):
    if f.__name__ != 'test':
        raise ValueError
    if f.__module__ != '__main__':
        raise ValueError
    if len(f.__code__.co_code) % 8 == 4:
        raise ValueError
    return f(*argv, **kw)
```

Writing correct wrapper becomes a challenge. That challenge could be complicated further:

```
def assess0(f, *argv, **kw):
    if len(f.__code__.co_code) % 8 == 0:
        kw['arg'] = True
        return f(*argv[1:], kw)
    else
        kw['arg'] = False
        return f(*argv[:-1], **kw)
```

Universal wrapper should handle both `assess0` and `assess4` correctly which is pretty impossible. And we have not touched `id` magic. Checking `id` would cast acceptable function in stone.

**Coding etiquette**

So you could not write a wrapper. Why someone bother to write one? Why function are so common when they could not guarantee behavior equivalence and could possible introduce non-trivial changes in code flow?

The simple answer is coding conventions. The famous substitution principle. Code should keep behavior properties when some object is substituted with another of the same type. Python put little focus on type nomination and enforcing. Rigorous type system is not a must, you could establish APIs and protocols through documentation and type annotation like the python language does.

Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute. OOP conventions are all in people minds. So python developers broke conventions requiring some non-stadard behavior for overriding `object` methods. This non-conventional OOP treatment make impossible to use decorators for transforming `__init__` and `__new__` methods.

**The final solution**

If python treats `__new__` so special then generic wrapper should do the same.

```
# simplest wrapper possible: just pass the args
def wraps(f):
    def call(*argv, **kw):
        # add some meaningful manipulations later
        return f(*argv, **kw)
    def call_new(*argv, **kw):
        # add some meaningful manipulations later
        return f(argv[0])
    if f is object.__new__:
        return call_new
    # elif other_special_case: pass
    else:
        return call
```

Now it could successfully pass the test

```
# check the wrapper behaves identically
class M:
    def __init__(this, param):
        this.param = param
M.__new__ = M.__new__
m1 = M(1)
M.__new__ = wraps(M.__new__)
m2 = M(2)
```

**The drawback** is that you should implement distinct workaround for any other convention breaking functions besides `__new__` to make your function wrapper semi-applicable in universal context. But it is the best you could get out of python.